# Javascript: Is it possible to download a file through Parse Cloud code?

Tags: file, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Just a simple question: 
In NodeJS's Express we are able to download a file via res.download(filepath, downloadAsFilename). or:

```
app.get("/download", (req, res)=> {
   res.download(filepath, downloadAsFilename); 
})
```

is it possible to do the same via Parse Cloud Code? Meaning to say by writing a cloud function that calls res.download instead of res.success?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the legacy `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` to download a file over HTTP and access the data via the `Parse.Cloud.HTTPResponse` buffer object. You also can use any NPM modules that allows you to get a file on Parse server

Read more: [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#httprequest)